# this.hostContainer is undefined in Acrobat scripting

Tags: pdf, acrobat

I have a query. Actually, I am using an acrobat 9 pro to create editable pdf and also have a submit button in pdf itself to submit a form to a backend server. My main concern is to send pdf data to the backend server for further processing. I am using this.hostContainer.postMessage(msg) to communicate between embedded pdf and the browser. The major problem here is this.hostContainer is always undefined in pdf scripting.

Also, I have been searching for this very long time and I could not find any solution though.

Some forums even say that Acrobat 9 pro have a problem with hostContainer.

Looking forward to your help. Thanks﻿

Comment: *"Acrobat 9 pro have a problem with hostContainer"* - where exactly does Adobe specify that `hostContainer` member?

Answer (score 1):

The HostContainer Object is only available when the PDF is being displayed in IE now, not Edge or any other modern browser. It's also not available at all on macOS or mobile. I suggest not bothering with it at all because you don't actually need to embed the PDF in a browser in order to submit the form data to a server. You just need the submit URL to be fully qualified and the submit button will work.

Comment: Thank you so much, Joel Geraci. Actually, I want to submit the pdf to secure API using session token in the request header which is only possible if I could communicate between the browser and embedded pdf.

Comment: I'd suggest you rethink your solution. HostContainer with PDF is just not a reliable long-term solution. In Acrobat / Reader, you can use the Net.HTTP methods to securely submit the data as well as set header values and authentication.

Comment: Yes, Joel Geraci, I agree with your solution but all my tokens are stored in local Storage in a browser which I cannot access from embedded pdf, acrobat scripting to set request header using Net.HTTP.